# Chunk/Stream API data using Node.js

Tags: node.js

We have requirement where we need to write a node application which can read URL of image from database (approx more than million). Use image-size npm package to retrieve image meta data like height, width. Here should be an API which can list out result.

I am able to console log data but when i convert it to API, i need to chunk data so it can start appearing on browser and i'm unable to do that and need help. Here is my code

```js
var express = require('express');

var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');
var sizeOf = require('image-size');
const sql = require('mssql');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const hostname = 'localhost';

var config1 = {
    user: '*********',
    password: '*********',
    server: '*********', 
    database: '*******',
    port: 1433,
    debug: true,
    options: {
        encrypt: false // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
    }
};

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    //res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

var finalResult = [];
sql.close();
sql.connect(config1, function (err) {
        
        if (err) console.log(err);
        const request = new sql.Request()
        var myQuery = `select imagename from media`;

        request.stream = true;
        request.query(myQuery);
        request.on('row', row => {
            
            //console.log('Image : ' + row.ImageUrl);    
            if (row.ImageUrl != ''){
                if (row.ImageUrl.indexOf('http') < 0)
                    row.ImageUrl = "http:" + row.ImageUrl;
                    
                var options = url.parse(row.ImageUrl);          
                
                
                http.get(options, function (response) {
                    
                    if (response.statusCode == 200)
                    {
                        var chunks = [];
                        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                        chunks.push(chunk);
                        }).on('end', function() {
                            var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                            //console.log(options.href);
                            //console.log(sizeOf(buffer).height);
                            var result = {};
                            result.MaskUrl = row.MaskUrl;
                            result.ImageUrl = options.href;
                            result.Height = sizeOf(buffer).height;    
                            result.Width = sizeOf(buffer).width;    
                            result.statusCode = 200;
                            finalResult.push(result);
                            //console.log(result);
                            console.log(finalResult);
                            res.write(result, function(){
                                res.end();
                            });
                            });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var result = {};
                        result.MaskUrl = row.MaskUrl;
                        result.ImageUrl = options.href;
                        result.Height = 0;
                        result.Width = 0;
                        result.statusCode = response.statusCode;
                        finalResult.push(result);
                        console.log(result);
                        res.write(result, function(){
                            res.end();
                        });
                        
                }

                    
                });

            }
        })

        request.on('error', err => {
            
            console.log ('Error for ' + row.ImageUrl );
        })

        request.on('done', err => {
            console.log('Last Time' + finalResult.length);
        })

        // request.query(myQuery,(err,result) =>{
        //     console.log(result);
        // });
        
    });
    console.log('Last Time' + finalResult.length);
    res.send(finalResult);
});

app.listen(port, hostname, function(){
    console.log('ImageSize running on PORT: ' + port);
});
```

I tried res.write, res.end without any success.

Comment: Recreate a **Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

The probable reason for your problem is that here:

```
res.write(result, function(){
    res.end();
});
```

You end and close the request just after the first image is read.

I would rewrite the code a little and use some functional framework, like [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet), to stream the data straight from the DB. As Nicholas pointed out it's not super easy to run your code so I'm writing blindly - but if you fix any of my obvious error this should just work:

First:

```
npm install scramjet JSONStream node-fetch
```

Next, try this code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var sizeOf = require('image-size');
const sql = require('mssql');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const hostname = 'localhost';
const {DataStream} = require('scramjet');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');

var config1 = {
    user: '*********',
    password: '*********',
    server: '*********',
    database: '*******',
    port: 1433,
    debug: true,
    options: {
        encrypt: false // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
    }
};

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){

    // you should consider not doing these two lines on each request, 
    // but I don't want to mess you code...
    sql.close(); 
    sql.connect(config1, function (err) {
        if (err) next(err);

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

        const request = new sql.Request();
        var myQuery = `select imagename from media`;

        request.stream = true;
        request.query(myQuery);

        const stream = new DataStream();
        request.on('row', row => stream.write(row));

        stream.filter(
                row => row.ImageUrl !== ''
            )
            .map(
                async row => {
                    if (row.ImageUrl.indexOf('http') !== 0) // url must start with http.
                        row.ImageUrl = "http:" + row.ImageUrl;

                    const response = await fetch(row.ImageUrl);
                    let size = {width:0, height:0};

                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        const buffer = await response.buffer();
                        size = sizeOf(buffer);
                    }

                    return {
                        MaskUrl: row.MaskUrl,
                        ImageUrl: row.ImageUrl,
                        Height: size.height,
                        Width: size.width,
                        statusCode: response.status
                    };

                }
            )
            .pipe(
                JSONStream.stringify()
            ).pipe(
                res
            );


        request.on('error', () => {
            res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            stream.end("{error:true}");
        });

        request.on('done', () => stream.end());

    });
});

app.listen(port, hostname, function(){
    console.log('ImageSize running on PORT: ' + port);
});
```